# How to calculate Gibbs free energy of diamond?

Tags: thermodynamics

How the effect of crystal structure on Gibbs free energy is calculated? For example, how the Gibbs free energy of diamond is 2.9 kJ/mol, while that of graphite is 0?

Answer (score 2):

More broadly, the free energy functions for phases of a number of elements, including carbon, are gathered in 'SGTE Data for Pure Elements', A. T. Dinsdale, CALPHAD 15(4), 317-425 (1991).  This provides a self-consistent set of free energy functions to use in phase diagram calculations.  For carbon, the source listed is P. Gustafson, Carbon 24, 169-176 (1986).  The free energy functions are listed in absolute terms, as well as for carbon phases relative to graphite. Diamond, relative to graphite, is

$1009 + 4.88 T - 0.01 T ln(T) + 135400 T^{-1} + 33.0E5 T^{-2}- 9E8 T^{-3} + G_{pres}$

Thus, at 298.15K, the free energy difference is 2.9 kJ/mol, but it rises with T so that at 1000K it is up to almost 6 kJ/mol.